# Admin Panel Order Detail page Does not show customer Address

Tags: magento

Everything was working fine, but now I can not see the customer address in order detail page in admin panel.

Comment: Specify which address Billing or Shipping? Check for any exceptions/logs

Comment: It does not show shipping address.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a broad question. First check you haven't installed anything recently. If you have, disable all your extensions and check again. The only reason why a shipping address wouldn't normally show is in case the order is virtual.

Comment: it was working fine, but showing problem since last week, also not sending order completion emails. I did not installed anything new.